# Is vs is to + verb

Tags: grammar, verbs, objects

I saw the following sentence while reading.

> I realized that all my peers do is read textbooks.

My question is whether the meaning of the sentence will change if the sentence is changed to

> I realized that all my peers do is to read textbooks.

I wonder if grammar of both sentences is correct and I wonder if there is any sentence structure that resembles the above for altered or unaltered meaning (if possible). Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think the second is wrong , while the first is correct : "All I want **to** do is **to** read" : Here the second "to" may or may not be deleted. "All I do is **to** read" : Here the "to" is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is absolutely wrong. The only situation that I can think of where a "to" in the second clause can be used in a similar setting is this. "I realized that all my peers advise (me to do) is to read textbooks.
It's a case of someone telling someone else "to" do something.
I realized that all my peers were told to work harder.

Comment: Given [how common that *optional* infinitive marker is](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22all+he+does+is+to%22) in OP's specific context, I don't think you can baldly dismiss it as "absolutely wrong".

Comment: Sorry, it sounds absolutely wrong is what I meant. I've never seen nor heard something like that. All they do is to read books. All my peers do is reading books. Sorry but both are still a no from me at least. If you flip it, it'll sound right at least. Reading books is all my peers do. I still wouldn't say 'To read books is all my peers do' though,  however that's just old vs new usage.

Comment: I'm not so keen on [*all she does is **to** clean*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22all+she+does+is+to+clean%22), but I have no problem with the gerund version [*all she does is **cleaning***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22all+she+does+is+cleaning%22). But I definitely *don't* like *All my friends do is **lazing around*** - so if there's any significant *consistency* about which exact contexts "allow" which verb forms (even for me as a single native speaker, let alone *most / all* of us), I certainly can't figure it out. Circumstances very much alter cases, here! :)

Comment: ...but that's a crucial distinction between the first sentence in you *answer*, and in your *comment*. I don't believe much of what "grammarians" say about valid / invalid syntax - so far as I'm concerned, almost everything native speakers say is valid *by definition*. So the assertion in your answer strikes me as "incorrect" - as opposed to the *comment*, where I find your position *interesting*. Are you in fact a native Anglophone? And your parents?

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not to include the "infinitive marker" ***to*** in OP's context is a stylistic choice, and that choice seems to have changed over time. It's irrelevant whether it's ***all*** they do, or ***what*** they do, so I think almost all instances contributing to [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20does%20is%20to%20argue%2Che%20does%20is%20argue&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) will match the current context...

[image]

I'd say ***[to] read textbooks*** is a "noun phrase", so syntactically it's the same as *[All I want for Christmas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-iFsxSNN2c) is **my two front teeth***. So it's worth noting that after *all/what [subject] [main verb] is [secondary verb-based element]* whether to include the infinitive marker is heavily dependent on the "main" verb...

> *All it **does** is [to?] annoy me*
> *What I **want** is **to** go home*
> *All I **need** is **to** sit down for a minute*
> *All he **knows** is **to** keep quiet*

Answer (score 0):

> I realized that all my peers do is read textbooks.
> My question is whether the meaning of the sentence will change if the sentence is changed to
> I realized that all my peers do is to read textbooks.

The examples do not sufficiently distinguish the function of the complement. Let us change "read" to "make":

The *“I realised that”* is irrelevant

*All that my peers do is make textbooks*

*All that my peers do is to make textbooks.*

*“That my peers do”* is irrelevant

*“Make textbooks”* and *“to make textbooks”* both define “**All**” in their own way:

We can now rephrase to capture the semantics:

*All that my peers do is make textbooks* ->   All *[of my peers]* make textbooks

*All that my peers do is to make textbooks.* -> All *[the action of my peers]* is towards the making of textbooks.

Comment: You seem to be saying that in *All he does is [**to**] argue* (optionally followed by additional text, such as *...for a referendum, ...with me, about the roster,...)*, the presence or absence of ***to*** determines whether "arguing" is the only thing he does, OR that he does a range of things which all *promote the merits of his argument*. I don't really buy that distinction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The effect of the "to" is basically the effect of a preposition on any noun phrase - it creates a modifier -in this case - a complement. The effect, in the example, is to define "all": either "all my peers" or "all my peers' actions".

Comment: Hmm. I think ***to*** in this context is an optional "infinitive marker", not a preposition. And like I said, I don't see how including ***to*** somehow magically extends the scope of the relevant verb from "directly and only" *(reading, making, arguing)* to "enabling / promoting" that activity.